# Multiple journeys on same data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

here's what I'm trying to do :
we have users that triggers multiple events (ie : `subscription`, `login`, `add_to_cart`...)
I'd like to have multiple journeys based on what the user does.

1. when they subscribe, I create a new contact in SFMC with basic information (`primary_key`, `email`, `name`...) and trigger the journey
2. when they login, I update the contact with the login date, and this will change the path in the journey
   this is working perfectly.

Now I'd like a second journey, that sends him a sms notification when the `add_to_cart` event has been fired.
I saw that it's not recommended to use the same DE for 2 different journeys, but I'd like to avoid resending all the user information for every events.

What is the proper way to do this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.